# php mysql database 1045 acces denied

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp\www\mctr\db.php on line 6**

I tried to make changes in `config.inc` that people on the internet did and fixed but didn't work for me help.

I got this error when trying to make connection and creating table.

My db connection

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = " ";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("1: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "2";
?>
```

My creating table file

```
<?php
    require_once "db.php";
    $t = "CREATE TABLE uyeler (
        id INT(7) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        isim VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
        kullanici_adi VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        sifre VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        skype VARCHAR(20) NULL,
        uye_tipi enum('Üye','Yönetici','Kurucu') NOT NULL default 'Üye',
        UNIQUE KEY email (email),
        UNIQUE KEY kullanici_adi (kullanici_adi),
        tolpam_indirilme INT(7) NULL,
        aylik_indirilme INT(7) NULL,
        kayit_tarihi TIMESTAMP
    )";

    $querySonucu = mysql_query($t);

    if ($querySonucu === TRUE) {print "Basarili!";} else {print "Hata!";}
    mysql_close();
?>
```

My `config.inc.php`

```
<?php
    /* Servers configuration */
    $i = 0;

    $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'a8b7c6d'; //What you want

    /* Server: localhost [1] */
    $i++;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Local Databases';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

    // Hidden databases in PhpMyAdmin left panel
    // $cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|sys)';

    // Allow connection without password
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

    // Suppress Warning about pmadb tables
    $cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;

    // To have PRIMARY & INDEX in table structure export
    $cfg['Export']['sql_drop_table'] = true;
    $cfg['Export']['sql_if_not_exists'] = true;

    $cfg['MySQLManualBase'] = 'http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/';
    /* End of servers configuration */
?>
```

Comment: Do you have the username and password that your database expects? (don't post the password)

Comment: you didn't choose a database and you're mixing MySQL APIs. Pretty obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DB connection file. Be sure your password is set as

```
$password = "";
```

and not

```
$password = " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your password? It seems you are using " ", i.e. a single space. For instance for xampp with standard configuration the password is empty ""